# Does the professor say "under the six" or anything else?

Tags: listening

At [31:50](https://youtu.be/6ThMzlHdKsI?t=31m50s) in the video, the professor said "It is **under the six**. It is absolutely impractical." And later at [31:54](https://youtu.be/6ThMzlHdKsI?t=31m54s) he told a joke where he also mentioned "under the six". But I have searched the google and the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Polynomial_time), only to find that such a phrase doesn't exist. Thus I think I recognized the speech wrongly. Could anybody who can recognize it correctly(or has the knowledge background to recognize that ambiguous speech correctly) please tell me what it exactly is?

Comment: Not my area, but I think he's saying N to the six, in other words N to the power of six, where the variable N stands for any given number.

Comment: @Araucaria Your recognition is much better than mine. That makes sense.

Comment: @Araucaria I feel like your comment should have been an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Araucaria has already pointed out, the spoken words are:

> It's *n* to the six, which is absolutely impractical.

"*n* to the the six" means "*n* raised to the power six". What the speaker is saying is that any solution would have a complexity of *O*(*n*<sup>6</sup>). Since solutions with complexity of less than *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>) are generally sought for to be computationally viable, *O*(*n*<sup>6</sup>) is hardly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

He is saying

> N<sup>6</sup>

which he goes on to say is an impractical number.

Comment: You might want to add how that is said in actual words. Then I can upvote your answer!

Comment: That's exactly what I am waiting for. But it seems that for listening issues StackExchange is not the best place to explain.